# Can Spyder show object documentation on hover?

Tags: spyder

Is there any way to get Spyder to show a popup tooltip when I hover over a function name, similar to the Visual Studio Code example below?

[image]

Spyder is showing a popup intellisense (or whatever the comparable term is in Spyder) window for code completion when I type an identifier and hit `.`, but I can't find a way to have it show function tooltips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality is already available and it'll be part of Spyder 4, to be released later in 2019.